# In a MySQL db, how to add a new column and make it a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

In a MySQL db, how to add a new column and make it a primary key?  The db already has four columns, one of which is a primary key.

Comment: The new column has already been added. So would I just need to do `ALTER TABLE foo DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(bar);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table t1 add column col1 varchar(20);

alter table t1 add primary key (columnname);
```

EDIT:

If you make "`show create table tablename`" commmnd you'll see the structure including the PK, if you want to delete it you can

`alter table tablename drop primary key` and then recreate the index

another possible solution is to create unique index it works as the primary key, only that the unique key let you can decide if it's null or not and you can have more than one per table.

```
alter table t1 add unique key (columnname);
```

Comment: Do I not need to change the previous primary key column?

Comment: I got `ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined`

Comment: that's because you already have a PK, and you have only one, I edited my answet

Comment: Right.  That's why I think what you gave above isn't really a solution.  I needed the new column to be a primary key, not a unique key.

Comment: then you'll need to delete the actual PK that you already have, try with the command that I gave you "show create table tablename" and you'll see the structure, remember that you can not have more than one PK per table

Comment: That's useful.  But I still don't know how to do what I need exactly.  Is it `ALTER TABLE foo DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(bar);`  ?

Comment: in your command line, your phpmyadmin, in your workbrench, etc, in your database manager (the software to manipulate your DB) put those commands, take a look to this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar int, DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(bar);
```

Better run this in one query if your table is large to make things faster.

Comment: For safety, I'd like to add the new column.  Make it primary key.  Then remove the previous primary key.  And delete the previous primary key column, all separately.

Comment: +1 as this seems will at least not suffer a `ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined` problem.

Comment: The new column has already been added.  So would I just do `ALTER TABLE foo DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(bar);`  ?